# kubernetes on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, kubernetes, systemd, ubuntu-16.04

I am testing and learning kubernetes. I am using ubuntu 16.04 and have been looking for the simple and straightforward installation guide, but have failed to find one... Any suggestion? My aim is to be able to run kubernetes as master on one ubuntu 16.04 laptop and later set up a second ubuntu 16.04 laptop easily join the cluster. I wonder if this can be achieved with the current version of kubernetes and the 16.04 version of ubuntu... Any pointer to a guide or useful resource will be appreciated... Best regards.

Comment: Do you want to learn how to use a Kubernetes cluster or how to deploy one? These are very different tasks.

Comment: I am learning how to install all the pieces in order to have a kubernetes cluster and run a docker application on top of a kubernetes cluster. I would like to start with having it set up with two nodes (in my case, two ubuntu 16.04 laptops... Is this possible? Then I will try to see if a kubernetes cluster can be set up on digital ocean with my two droplets... or how to get the two droplets running ubuntu 16.04 join to form a kubernetes cluster and run docker applications...

Answer (score 1):

You could check the way to bring up a single-node cluster which is via [cluster/get-kube-local.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ef0c9f0c5b8efbba948a0be2c98d9d2e32e0b68c/cluster/get-kube-local.sh). It shows you how one could use hyperkube to bring up a cluster.

If you want to get into the underlying details, the other method is to check out the contents of [hack/local-up-cluster.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/9fc1d61ab70c3d72cb6bf16d5d6b002074a0f6cd/hack/local-up-cluster.sh). This brings up each component separately, such as:

- kube-apiserver
- kube-proxy
- kube-dns
- kube-controller-manager

One could potentially use the same steps to create a two-node cluster as you stated in your question.

Comment: cluster/get-kube-local.sh does not complete... It get stuck on the following task: Detected existing kubectl binary. Skipping download.
Creating a local cluster:
 Starting kubelet...SUCCESS
 Waiting for master components to start...........................................................................................................................................................................................^

Comment: Not sure why the cluster is not created. I am running the script on ubuntu 16.04 ... I wonder if the localhost:8080 as defined in the script gets assigned that specific port... I checked there was no other container using the same port...

Comment: @user3669547 You may want to check `kubectl version`. If that returns a server version string, the server is up. It is possible that it has already started running. It happens sometimes that it states that it's waiting for components to start when it has already started them. You can check by running `docker ps` to see that it did spin up the right containers.

Comment: using docker ps... only the main kubernetes container is running... all others get created and exit immediately... doing docker ps -qa shows a growing number of containers exited... some of them are named master, proxy, Not sure what is doing this.

Comment: running kubectl version returns the following output: sudo kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"2", GitVersion:"v1.2.0", GitCommit:"5cb86ee022267586db386f62781338b0483733b3", GitTreeState:"clean"}
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?.... I am suspecting that the api server is not accessible. It is supposed to be localhost:8080.

Comment: I see. Looks like it didn't work. Might be worth some investigation. You could try the kubernetes slack channel and the folks out there should be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this matches your needs, but Minikube is IMO the fastes way to run a Kubernetes cluster locally: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube

Besides that: setting up a multi-node cluster isn't a simple task, because you have to set up the overlay network and Kubernetes consist of many components.

Comment: can using flannel and etcd resolve the networking and service discovery problem? I have seen tutorials for CoreOS and other major cloud providers, but not ubuntu 16.04...

Comment: I am currently going through this guide: http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode/

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide in the Kubernetes docs especially for Ubuntu: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes.github.io/blob/release-1.4/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu.md

Comment: The guide says it was tested ok on ubuntu 14.0 but cannot work on ubuntu 15.00 which uses systemd. I understand that ubuntu 16.04 also uses systemd (and not upstart). This is the reason why I did not try to follow the guide provided in the kubernetes docs... Unless someone tells me how to adapt the instructions to the systemd... where and what to change... that is not clear to me at this stage. thanks for suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

I came across an article to install Kubernetes in Ubuntu 16.04.
https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-quickly-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu/

I would suggest you to go with latest Kubernetes version installation as new version is supported with some extensions like deployments, replica sets(similar to replication controller).

Answer (score -1):

Please try https://github.com/nitinmidha/kube-cluster It is tested with kube v1.4.6 and Ubuntu 16.04

These are bash scripts written to provide "Kubernetes HA(multi master with etcd clustering, multi minion) Secure(Client Certification on etcd and kube-api-server) Cluster on Ubuntu 16.04"

**Limitations**

1. https://master_ip/ui will not work as master can not reach to containers. Dashboard is hosted as a separate internal service available on minion nodes on port 9090 using dashboard service ip address. If required it can be proxied through any reverse proxy server like NGINX. Or Service can expose NodePort and can be available outside the cluster
2. kube-apiserver exposes port 8080 for 127.0.0.1 interface on master. Once https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/13598 is fixed and avialble, --insecure-port will be set to 0.
3. Flannel does not secure data packets. There is a PR (https://github.com/coreos/flannel/pull/290) to add ipsec backend that would encrypt data packets. Once this feature is avialble, setup will be configured to secure it.
4. kubelet and kube-proxy does not support multiple kube-apiserver address. So we still have a single point of failure, as only one ip address can be configured. To workaround, we can expose all the master nodes under an external load balancer and then point to that address. Issue is logged and worked upon in kubernetes. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/19152

**Features**

1. Multi Master Cluster with ETCD clustering.
2. TLS communication and client cert authentication between ETCD client and peer communication.
3. TLS communication and client cert authentication between all kube-components
4. Flannel is used for networking. Flannel does not support TLS yet.
5. Node can be Master Only, Worker Only and Master-Worker mode. Master Only nodes do not have flannel/kubelet and kube-proxy, so will not be able to reach to pods. Also command 'kubelet get nodes' will not show this node.
6. Option to connect to existing ETCD Cluster with TLS.